# Runtime error while running a simple code in GCC compiler for C

Tags: c, gcc, greatest-common-divisor

Following is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main ()
{
   int n1, n2, min, GCD, i;
   printf("Enter two nos. : ");
   scanf(" %d %d", &n1, &n2);
   min=(n1<n2)? n1: n2;
   for (i=0, i<min; ++i)
   { 
      if(n1%i==0 && n2%i==0)
          GCD=i;
   }
    printf("GCD is %d", GCD);
}
```

Please point out the mistake which is causing runtime error.

Comment: What is the exact error message you are encountering?

Comment: Initialize `i` with `2` instead of `0` in loop, otherwise `n1%i==0 && n2%i==0` will be equivalent to `n1%0==0 && n2%0==0` for first iteration which will cause the problem.

Comment: Not relevant to your problem, but `void main()` should be `int main(void)`.

Answer (score 4):

The modulus operator `%` will be problem when `i` is equal to zero. There is no need to start with `i = 1`, every number is divisible by `1`. Start with `i = 2`.

Also, you have a problem in the `for` loop, most likely due to a typo.

```
for (i=0, i<min; ++i)
       ^^^ That should be ;
```

Here's the loop with both fixes:

```
for (i=2; i<min; ++i)
{
   if(n1%i==0 && n2%i==0)
      GCD=i;
}
```

Other suggestions to improve your code:

1. Change the return type of `main` to `int`. That' what the standard expects.
2. Initialize `GCD` to `1` instead of leaving it uninitialized. You know that it has to be at least `1`.

Answer (score 0):

```
 for (i=0, i<min; ++i) is wrong syntax

 for (i=0; i<min; ++i) is correct syntax
```

`(n1%i)` is actually dividing by 0; this is the reason for runtime error

return type of main is `int` as per standard